# unable to Authenticate on RESTAPI

Tags: python, rest

```
I want to access Snov.io API but there is Error Unauthenticated. but I authenticated. and I can print Acces token too. am I missing anything here?

    import requests
    import json
    
    
    def get_access_token():
        params = {
            'grant_type': 'client_credentials',
            'client_id': '59e814b92ded8ed6b5537718495bf2a5',
            'client_secret': '9cc7012893ff220c6935440b8e216ac1'
        }
    
        res = requests.post(
            'https://api.snov.io/v1/oauth/access_token', data=params)
        resText = res.text.encode('ascii', 'ignore')
    
        return json.loads(resText)['access_token']
    
    
    def user_lists(token):
        params = {'access_token': token}
    
        res = requests.get(
            'https://api.snov.io/v1/get-user-campaigns', data=params)
    
  
    return json.loads(res.text)


token = get_access_token()
resp = user_lists(token)
print(token)
print(resp)
```

get_access_token() is working fine . that's what I am assuming because it's return CODE 200 and access_toke also.

user_lists() return error

**ERROR**

<Response [401]>

Comment: Which function returns the 401 response in question?

Comment: user_lists() return error

Comment: `get_access_token()` seems to hit the correct endpoint with the expected parameters, but you haven't processed the response data in `res` to the point where you would be extracting the `access_token` value from the returned JSON. You're then attempting to pass the entirety of that object as the `access_token`, instead of just the `access_token` value by itself.

Comment: Further: why have you elected to call `get_access_token()` in both your global scope, as well as in `user_lists()`? Doesn't that seem a bit duplicative? Regardless, the `token` you're attempting to pass in `user_lists` is actually a `Response` object (which is what is being returned from `get_access_token()`), and not the token itself. It's not clear how you expected `token` in this context to contain *only* the `access_token` without first parsing it from the JSON response.

Comment: I was printing and checking token. that why I called twice.  thanks for the help. I am working on this thing and see if it works.

Comment: I rewrote the code by keeping points in mind. still got the same error.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233630/discussion-between-qureshi-owais-and-esqew).